# LightGBM fit parameter when used in sklearn stacking

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I'm using lightgbm with sklearn `stacking` method, but I encounter a problem which is :

How can I setting some parameters in `LGBMRegressor.fit` function?

This is my code for now :

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
estimators = [
    ('lr', RidgeCV()),
    ('svr', LinearSVR(random_state=42)),
    ('lgb', LGBMRegressor())
]
reg = StackingRegressor(
    estimators=estimators,
    final_estimator=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10,
                                          random_state=42)
)
reg.fit(X,Y)
```

But I want to set `num_boost_round` and `early_stopping_rounds` in `LGBMRegressor.fit`, how can I achieve that when I used with `StackingRegressor.fit`

※Note : 
Without using stacking method, I can implement with

```
lgb = LGBMRegressor()
lgb.fit(X,Y, num_boost_round=20000, early_stopping_rounds=1000)
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Not yet, I guess it can not be set separately for each models since all models should be decided when to stop training by StackingRegressor. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @azuber, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is not that you cannot specify `num_boost_round` and `early_stopping_round` in the fit. Those parameters are not officially supported according to the [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html#lightgbm.LGBMRegressor), but if you were using them, you would be putting them in the instantiation call.

```
lgb = LGBMRegressor(num_boost_round=20000, early_stopping_rounds=1000)
```

I think the problem is that if you are trying to use early_stopping, you have to put evaluation sets into the `fit()` call, which is definitely not supported (at least not in the current version).

You can still get what you want, you just have to wrap your model into a class that supports the API, essentially moving those parameters to the object instantiation:

```
import lightgbm as ltb
class MyWrappedLGBR:
    def __init__(self, fit_parameters: dict):
        self.fit_parameters = fit_parameters

    def fit(self, X, y):
        my_data_set = ltb.Dataset(data = X, label=y)
        ltb.train(params=self.fit_parameters, train_set=my_data_set)

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.model.predict(X)
```

And create your estimator as:

```
my_params = {
    'num_boost_round': 20000,
    'early_stopping_rounds': 1000,
    'valid_sets': your_validation_set
}
my_lgb = MyWrappedLGBR(my_params)
```

Then, when `StackingRegressor` makes calls to `fit` and `predict`, it will behave the way you want.

If you really want to stick to the sklearn API and are willing to take the risk that you will get unexpected behavior, you can create a wrapper class more in the vein of that API as well:

```
class MySKLWrappedLGBR:
    def __init__(self, my_model, fit_parameters: dict):
        self.model = my_model
        self.fit_parameters = fit_parameters

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.model.fit(X, y, **self.fit_parameters)

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.model.predict(X)
```

Then something like this **might*  work:

```
lgb = LGBMRegressor(num_boost_round=20000, early_stopping_rounds=1000)

my_eval_params = {
    'valid_sets': your_validation_set
}

my_wrapped_lgb = MySKLWrappedLGBR(lgb, my_eval_params)
```

But again, none of this functionality is officially supported in the Sklearn API, so it is better to use the earlier wrapper class that uses the Dataset API.